# Umbraco - xslt variable into data attribute

Tags: variables, xslt, umbraco

I have a value in xslt and I need to put it into the data-time attribute of the p tag

```
 <xsl:value-of select="current()/eventTime" />
 <p class="time" data-time="1">Duration: <xsl:value-of select="current()/eventTime" /> hour(s)</p>
```

this creates an error

```
<p class="time" data-time="<xsl:value-of select="current()/eventTime" />">Duration: <xsl:value-of select="current()/eventTime" /> hour(s)</p>
```

any idea how I achieve this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

"Attribute Value Templates" are your friend here

```
<p class="time" data-time="{current()/eventTime}">
   Duration: <xsl:value-of select="current()/eventTime" /> hour(s)
</p>
```

The curly braces indicate that this is an Attribute Value Template, and so contains an expression to be evaluated.

Note that an alternate way would be to use the **xsl:attribute** element

```
<p class="time">
   <xsl:attribute name="data-time">
       <xsl:value-of select="current()/eventTime" />
   </xsl:attribute>
   Duration: <xsl:value-of select="current()/eventTime" /> hour(s)
</p>
```

This is not so elegant though. You would only really need to do it this way if wanted a dynamic attribute name.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<xsl:variable name="eventtime" select="current()/eventTime"/>

<xsl:element name="p">
  <xsl:attribute name="class">time</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="data-time">
     <xsl:value-of select="$eventtime" />
  </xsl:attribute>
  Duration: 
  <xsl:value-of select="$eventtime" />
</xsl:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `<xsl:attribute>` it's also possible to use the short form in '`{}`' brackets. In your case it would be like this:

`<xsl:value-of select="current()/eventTime" />
     <p class="time" data-time="{$eventtime}">Duration: <xsl:value-of select="current()/eventTime" /> hour(s)</p>`